# Ansys Fluent: how to change the temperature digit precision in writing to file XY-plot?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, ansys, ansys-workbench, fluent

I want to write to file data from XY-Plot with temperature depending on the location. In Axis menu I set a max precision (9) for X and Y. However, Fluent writes data like this

```
293.094 0.000364067
293.094 0.000361604
293.094 0.000359141
293.095 0.000356678
293.095 0.000354215
293.096 0.000351752
293.096 0.000349289
293.096 0.000346826
...
```

I need a data about temperature as precise as possible (cause I want to use it in another program) but Fluent writes to xy-file only 3 digits after the decimal point despite my settings (for example, 293.194 instead of 293.093621..). I set precision this way for a many times for another physical quantities (velocity, heat flux at walls etc.), and there was always good precision exporting to in xy-files. But not for temperature.

I tried to google this problem but didn't find any special information for Fluent about this case.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: what do the Fluent help files say? probably better than google...

Comment: The single-precision solvers in Fluent will only produce about 6 significant figures anyway, and that is what your sample output contains. If you really *need* temperatures to an accuracy of better than 0.001 degrees, you must have a *very* specialized (and strange) application in mind.

Comment: @SolarMike Unfortunately, I didn't find the answer to my question in the documentation.

Comment: Please, don't [cross-post](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/30037/9667).